# Pandas on Linux importing UTF 8 (BOM) csv with BOM header as cleartext in column names

Tags: python, pandas, csv, utf-8, read-csv

Difference on importing csv data on Linux and MacOS

Hello everyone,

when importing a csv file with `pandas.read_csv` using UTF8 (BOM) encoding under Linux, the first column name contains the BOM as cleartext, e.g. `\\xEF\\xBB\\xBFColumnName`.

When i do the same under MacOS, everything is beautiful. Why does this happen?

I use python-3.10.12 and pandas-2.1.2.

Comment: More to the point, why does your file have a BOM in the first place?

Comment: Just implement one "toolbox function" (so a library file which you will use in many project, with helper functions written by you) which check and remove all BOM from column names. It is easy and useful. The problem will not become easier. Note: the best way it is to avoid to have BOM in CSV. Future Unicode will legalize BOM more then now, so... remove BOM as default step, also if there is not (yet) a BOM.

Comment: I have to include a BOM because the file has to be imported in some legacy ERP-DB (ProAlpha) which needs a BOM to correctly import UTF8.

Comment: @tripleee if you look at all the questions asking why Excel or *any other* application opens UTF8 files as Latin1, you'll understand why. Sure, the UTF8 standard says not to use BOMs, but *in real life* applications have no way of differentiating between UTF8 and any other codepage until they read the entire file and look for invalid bytes

Comment: @JanJansen use `encoding='utf8-sig'` instead of `utf8`. Applications generate CSVs with BOMs because it's impossible to guess the encoding of a file before opening it and reading it to the end, without asking the user. And even after reading the entire file, it can only guess. In any OS, when you double-click on a file the application that opens it will either check for a BOM or read it using the current "default" encoding, whether that's called LC_LANG or "Default codepage".

Comment: I find the different behaviour strange, can you share the code for people to reproduce this?

Comment: `Difference on importing csv data on Linux and MacOS` I've seen even weirder things - Linux behaving one way, MacOS behaving in *two* different ways. MacOS isn't Linux and there are different LC_ settings for the GUI and terminals. In that case, a developer had set the terminal to work the same way as his Linux box and incorrectly set Latin1 on both. The *GUI* kept using UTF8

Comment: PS: Which exact Pandas version is used in both environments? Only Pandas 2.x explicitly says that `utf-8` is the default.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not an issue with pandas but with printf behaviour when used in a makefile:

Given a file target.csv in UTF-8 (no-BOM) with contents:

```
colA;colB:...
```

and a Makefile containing a target like:

```
target.csv:
    python3 somescript.py
    mv -v $@ $@~
    printf '\xEF\xBB\xBF' | cat - $@~ > $@
```

a
`make target.csv`

leads to a target.csv containing

```
\xEF\xBB\xBFcolA;colB;...
```

as plain text and encoding is shown in editor (e.g. VSCode or VIM) as UTF-8.

But when directly issuing `printf '\xEF\xBB\xBF' | cat - target.csv~ > target.csv` in a bash prompt, file is correctly encoded as UTF-8 (BOM):

```
colA;colB:...
```

This is correctly done on MacOS.

I will put this question in a new thread because it is not an issue with `pandas` or `python` but with `make` / `printf`.

Comment: And that shows why you're supposed to extract a [mcve] first. That claimed OS dependency in the behaviour would have been clarified long ago.